# Обновление текста TextView android

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, android-scrollview

Существует TextView, который заполняется следующим способом

```
for (int q = 0; q < divinationAnInt; q++) {
            descriptionTextView.append(q + 1 + ". " + descriptionStrings[9][q] + "\n" +
                    descriptionStrings[8][(flipInts[q] * 25) + randomInts[q]] + "\n" +
                    descriptionStrings[buttonNum + (flipInts[q] * 4)][randomInts[q]] + "\n\n");
    }
descriptionTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Код берет информацию из разных мест, но это не суть, главное что он не устанавливает а дополняет TextView.

По нажатию кнопки текст должен обновиться.
Чтобы удалить старый текст я использую `descriptionTextView.setText("")`.
Но в этом варианте есть минус, при обновлении прокрутка TextView остается в середине, и соответственно текст читается не сначала, а откуда получится, и приходится вручную крутить до верха.
Как установить автоматическую прокрутку вверх при обновлении информации.

Пробовал в `xml` файле прописать `gravity`, но результата это не дало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
descriptionTextView.scrollTo(0,0);
```

[scrollTo(x,y)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#scrollTo(int,%20int)) - метод класса View.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло